# Nifi CPU Spike in Merge Content

Tags: apache-nifi

Apache NiFi is spiking the CPU to 100% and the specific node gets disconnected from the cluster.

We have 3 nodes cluster,

each with 8 core, and 64 GB RDM and 40 GB memory allocated to the JVM

In Merge Content when processing 2 million + small flow small flow files ( size of all files around 300 MB), NiFi node cpu reaches 100% and node gets disconnected and data never gets processed,

I am using defragment strategy in merge content.

I tried changing the nifi.queue.swap.threshold to 1,000,00 but it does not help.

Any hints on how to deal with this ?

[image: Merge Content Details]

Comment: 40 GB memory allocated to the JVM or to NiFi? could you share all the parameters of merge content processor?